# How to Access a list of titles(elements) from an array by inputting a single word?

Tags: python

I wrote a program that reads in a file. The name of the file was passed into my program as a command-line parameter. Each line of the file contained 3 fields, separated by a vertical bar, or pipe ("|"). 
The file contained information about books so each line contains a title(ex. Les Miserables), an author, and a genre which I put into three arrays:

```
title = []
author = []
genre = []
```

I am trying to input a word like "Les" and get the specific elements from the arrays and print it like "(Fiction), Les Miserables by Victor Hugo".

This is my code so far:

```
for word in myArray:
fields = word.split(|)
title.append(fields[0])
author.append(fields[1])
genre.append(fields[2])
entry = raw_input()
if entry == T or t:

titlEntry = raw_input("Please enter title:")
n = len(title)
for i in range(0,n):
if titlEntry == i:
print "(" + genre[i] + ") " + title[i] + " by " + author[i]
```

Please help

Comment: Do you need searching item by one word entry in title? Or the match should be exact?

Comment: What happens when you input `ict`. Do you expect to get a response about V"ict"or Hugo?

Comment: Format your code. What you posted is not valid Python.

Comment: Also, there's no real question here. What's wrong with your code? What do you need actual help with? All you have is a dump of requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not the way to do it; a dictionary would be better and I would ask you look into other structures as well. Also, think about sanitizing the input you read from the command line.  However, to get you going, you are close.  Try:

```
titlEntry = raw_input("Please enter title:")
n = len(title)
for i in range(0,n):
    if titlEntry == title[i]:
        print "(" + genre[i] + ") " + title[i] + " by " + author[i]
```

Comment: A custom object would be best. You could then define a search method on the object and call it for each element of the sequence. +1 for the idea.

Comment: That being said, please don't encourage incomplete questions by answering them until OP asks a proper question.